# I am trying to create a Featured Videos webpart using oob features in sharepoin 2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

i am now trying to create a featured videos webpart using oob features of sharepoint 2013.
on click on the play button the video must have smooth streaming as well..

any help is much appreciated

regards
keerthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

am actually getting the scroll bar and the entire site is getting opened i wanted only the video .. without any scroll bar.. and a thumbnail and a play button.. kinly help please....
i cannot use media webpart as i am working in sharpeoint 2013 foundation version.. al thanks in advance

Comment: please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Content Editor Web Part and either use iFrame or embed code from your favorite video streaming site. The streaming quality and "smmotheness" is determined mostley by your internet connection and the capability of your favorite video streaming site.

[image]

Reference: [Play video and media files in SharePoint 2013 sites](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.se/2013/04/play-video-and-media-files-in.html)

Comment: Hi thanks a ton for ur response i have added a content editor webpart and embeded code in it.. but i need to get a thumbnail of the video and then it should play after clicking play. this is not hapening.please help

Comment: hi am trying to use the content editor webpart and embed the code.
but i need to find ways to pass the url dynamically from a list to the code to be embeded. 
can u help me out in this?